# How do I add a button with an image to a menu in PyGtk, using XML?

Tags: python, xml, gtk

I am using a menu model created using `Gtk.Builder` from XML to create a popover, and I'm wondering whether I can use XML to add a button with an image to the popover. Here's my code:

```
import gi
import sys

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk

MENU_XML = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
    <menu id="app-popover">
        <button>
        </button>
        <section>
            <item>
                <attribute name="label">Test action</attribute>
                <attribute name="action">app.sample-action</attribute>
            </item>
        </section>
    </menu>
</interface>"""

class App(Gtk.Application):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self, *args, application_id="org.example.myapp", **kwargs)
        self.window = None

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

        self.action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("sample-action")
        self.action.connect("activate", self.on_action_activate)

        self.add_action(self.action)

    def do_activate(self):
        if not self.window:
            self.window = AppWindow(application=self)
            self.window.present()

    def on_action_activate(self, *args):
        print("Action blah")

class AppWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Gtk.ApplicationWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Get the menu model from the xml
        builder = Gtk.Builder.new_from_string(MENU_XML, -1)
        popover_menu = builder.get_object("app-popover")

        # Create the popover
        self.popover_button = Gtk.MenuButton(menu_model=popover_menu)
        self.box = Gtk.VBox()
        self.box.pack_start(self.popover_button, False, False, 0)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.maximize()

        self.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run(sys.argv)
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
(problem_how_to_add....py:46936): Gtk-ERROR **: 18:40:15.248: failed to add UI: Element <button> not allowed inside <menu>
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I also tried adding the lines

```
self.popover = self.popover_button.get_popover()
self.popover.add(Gtk.Button.new_from_icon_name("document-print-symbolic", 1))
```

after I create `self.popover_button` in `AppWindow.__init__`, but I got another error:

```
(problem_how_to_add....py:47063): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:44:46.591: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkButton to a GtkPopover, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkPopover can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkStack
```

I *also* tried using the lines

```
self.popover = self.popover_button.get_popover()
self.popover.get_children()[0].add(Gtk.Button.new_from_icon_name("document-print-symbolic", 1))
```

instead (`self.popover.get_children()[0]` returns an instance of `Gtk.Stack`), but even though there are no error messages, there's no button in the popover; just the menu item. Is there a way to add a button to a popover created this way, that looks like a `Gtk.Button`, has an image, and can be connected to an action?